# Creating library in JavaScript - setting "this" keyword relative to instance for all functions

Tags: javascript, this, library-design

I have developed a draft of a library, and coming from a OOP Java background, have a problem setting/accessing the correct "this"-keyword.

Each instance is linked to a canvas, which it draws to using various settings, instantiated like so (commands return **this**, so chainable):

```
var ffc = new FatFontCreator()
            .setup({
                canvasID    : "#mapCanvas",
                nestingDepth: 5
            })
            .drawNumber(args);
```

The functionality of the object is set in the **prototype** property:

```
FatFontCreator.prototype.settings = {
    dataSet : {
        highestMagnitude    : 5,
        someFunction : function() {
            console.log(this);
        }
    }

etc...
```

The main **problem** I have is to ensure the value of **this** to be the relevant object, as I expect some functionality to be called as a callback.

In order to set the this I bind them within the constructor, which replaces the existing functions of the object:

```
this.settings.dataSet.someFunction = this.settings.dataSet.someFunction.bind(this);
```

Which is **not** working since it changes the actual prototype function, and as you can only bind a function once, it doesn't work for more than one instance.

**EDIT**: The constructor looks like this

```
function FatFontCreator() {
    this.canvas = undefined;
    this.canvasContext = undefined;
    etc.

    return this;
}
```

My **question**: is there an easy way to bind **this** without overwriting the prototype method? 
Alternatively, will I have to declare all of the functions which I want to bind to the current instance in the constructor?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mhcgolds/xvn29n72/)?

Comment: You might want to look at Underscore's `_.bindAll`.

Comment: @torazaburo Thank you I will have a look at that.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Check out the Edit, that's what is basically happening at the moment